# Can we run two 'slave' nodes on the same machines?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, mesos-chronos

We are running a 3 node mesos cluster and mesos master is running on each node. Also, 2 slaves are running on each node. Is this a good practice? 2 slaves on each cluster won't be sending too much offer and end up being overloaded? What is the recommended config for 3 nodes cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Thread from Mesos User Mailing List](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/092e4ba44f46d28fe66f390047e5db2ca6de69d4f75bd6209e2d7748@%3Cuser.mesos.apache.org%3E)

> It depends on your isolation setting (mainly cgroup, or any node level
>   resources). In general, we don't recommend folks use multiple agents on a
>   node.
>
> It's possible to make it work by setting `cgroup_root` separately for
>   MesosContainerizer. For DockerContainerizer, currently, we hard code
>   `DOCKER_NAME_PREFIX`, making it not possible to use two agents on a node
>   properly.
>
> Running Docker containers won't work properly because restarting one agent
>   will cause Docker containers managed by the other agent to be deleted.